# Xcode unable to build iOS app target with LibTorch 1.13.0 installed via CocoaPods due to undefined symbols compilation error

Tags: ios, xcode, pytorch, cocoapods, libtorch

I am trying to deploy a PyTorch model on an iOS project. When I was building for the whole project, I got an `Undefined symbols:` error from the console.

Here is the pod file I am using:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '14.3'

target 'abc' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'LibTorch', '1.13.0'
  pod 'LibTorchvision', '0.14.0'

end
```

Here is the detailed messages from the console:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _cblas_cgemm, referenced from:
      at::native::cpublas::gemm(at::native::TransposeType, at::native::TransposeType, long long, long long, long long, c10::complex<float>, c10::complex<float> const*, long long, c10::complex<float> const*, long long, c10::complex<float>, c10::complex<float>*, long long) in libtorch_cpu.a[arm64][148](CPUBlas.cpp.o)
  _cblas_dgemm, referenced from:
      at::native::cpublas::gemm(at::native::TransposeType, at::native::TransposeType, long long, long long, long long, double, double const*, long long, double const*, long long, double, double*, long long) in libtorch_cpu.a[arm64][148](CPUBlas.cpp.o)
  _cblas_sgemm, referenced from:
      at::native::cpublas::gemm(at::native::TransposeType, at::native::TransposeType, long long, long long, long long, float, float const*, long long, float const*, long long, float, float*, long long) in libtorch_cpu.a[arm64][148](CPUBlas.cpp.o)
  _cblas_zgemm, referenced from:
      at::native::cpublas::gemm(at::native::TransposeType, at::native::TransposeType, long long, long long, long long, c10::complex<double>, c10::complex<double> const*, long long, c10::complex<double> const*, long long, c10::complex<double>, c10::complex<double>*, long long) in libtorch_cpu.a[arm64][148](CPUBlas.cpp.o)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried to install `LibTorch '1.9.0'` from CocoaPods and it could be built into the current Xcode iOS project correctly. So I am wondering why this happened...

In addition, although `LibTorch '1.9.0'` could be built into the iOS project, the PyTorch model also has some issues as stated [here](https://github.com/Cambridge-ICCS/FTorch/issues/37). So I might still have to find a solution out...

Comment: My guess is that your model.pt has been exported with a version of pytorch that is incompatible with Libtorch version. So if you export with torch==1.11, you'll have to use Libtorch 1.11. But this is only a guess. I need more information, for example the specifc stacktrace in Xcode.